# How to declare inherited inbuilt protocol so that it can be imported from another framework or app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, objective-c++, language-interoperability

I am unable to call this swift file from a different app/framework as am getting the below error.

> "Unknown class name 'WKScriptMessageHandler'"

This is the mySwift.swift which I have declared in a framework.

```
@objcMembers public class HSIWKJavascriptBridge : NSObject, WKScriptMessageHandler{
    public func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        if message.name == "test", let messageBody = message.body as? String {
            print(messageBody)
        }
    }
}
```

swift compiler generated this code automatically  while  compiling.

```
@class WKUserContentController;
@class WKScriptMessage;

SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC5MyFwk21HSIWKJavascriptBridge")
@interface HSIWKJavascriptBridge : NSObject <WKScriptMessageHandler>
- (void)userContentController:(WKUserContentController * _Nonnull)userContentController didReceiveScriptMessage:(WKScriptMessage * _Nonnull)message;
- (nonnull instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

Now the error is WKScriptMessageHandler is not auto declared like

```
@class WKUserContentController;
@class WKScriptMessage;
```

due to which I am not able to use the framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with your same `HSIWKJavascriptBridge` swift class in my Project setup. I was able to use this class in my Obj-C files without any problem.

Since `WKScriptMessageHandler` is a `protocol`, it will not be forward declared as other classes (`WKUserContentController`, `WKScriptMessage`) in swift compiler generated code.

Please make sure `import WebKit` is added in your Swift file.